# upgrading existing config.add_route, pyramid 1.4 to 1.10

Tags: python-2.7, view, upgrade, pyramid

Code I'm working on:

```
def add(self, path, view, method='GET'):
        url = _join_url_paths(self.path_prefix, path)
        id_ = hashlib.md5('%s-%s' % (url, method)).hexdigest()
        view = _join_view_paths(self.view_prefix, view)
        if id_ in _routes and env.name == 'dev':
            mlog.debug('Detected duplicate route: %s, %s' % (url, view))
        _routes[id_] = Route(id_, url, view, method, self.model, self.parent)
        if self.model and path == '/' and self.model not in _model_routes:
            _model_routes[self.model] = _routes[id_]
        self.config.add_route(id_, url, view=view, request_method=method)
```

This works perfectly on pyramid  1.4 and so far I've taken a look into 1.4 source code and 1.10 source code here's the difference I found But I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

**Reference 1.4**

```
class RoutesConfiguratorMixin(object):
    @action_method
    def add_route(self,
                  name,
                  pattern=None,
                  view=None,
                  view_for=None,
                  permission=None,
                  factory=None,
                  for_=None,
                  header=None,
                  xhr=None,
                  accept=None,
                  path_info=None,
                  request_method=None,
                  request_param=None,
                  traverse=None,
                  custom_predicates=(),
                  view_permission=None,
                  renderer=None,
                  view_renderer=None,
                  view_context=None,
                  view_attr=None,
                  use_global_views=False,
                  path=None,
                  pregenerator=None,
                  static=False,
                  **predicates):
```

**Reference 1.10**

```
class RoutesConfiguratorMixin(object):
    @action_method
    def add_route(
        self,
        name,
        pattern=None,
        factory=None,
        for_=None,
        header=None,
        xhr=None,
        accept=None,
        path_info=None,
        request_method=None,
        request_param=None,
        traverse=None,
        custom_predicates=(),
        use_global_views=False,
        path=None,
        pregenerator=None,
        static=False,
        **predicates
    ):
```

Notice that there's no parameter `view` in `add_route` in version 1.10 of the pyramid, any suggestion? I'm taking a look into the changelogs, If I happen to find it earlier this could be an interesting bit of solution to be posted on the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the change notes to [1.5a2 (2013-09-22), Backwards Incompatibilities](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/changes.html#id52):

> Removed the ability to pass the following arguments to `pyramid.config.Configurator.add_route`: `view`, `view_context`, `view_for`, `view_permission`, `view_renderer`, and `view_attr`. Using these arguments had been deprecated since Pyramid 1.1. Instead of passing view-related arguments to `add_route`, use a separate call to `pyramid.config.Configurator.add_view` to associate a view with a route using its `route_name` argument. Note that this impacts the `pyramid.config.Configurator.add_static_view` function too, because it delegates to `add_route`.

For example:

```
self.config.add_route(id_, url)
self.config.add_view(view=my_view_callable, route_name=id_, request_method=method)
```

See the docs on [View Configuration](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html) for more information.  I prefer using function decorators for view configuration.